# Backstage failing to start with Schema Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, backstage

I have been testing Backstage and all was going well till I did a `yarn install` this afternoon and now the whole thing has died on me :)

Whenever I try to run `yarn dev` it errors out with

```
[0] Loaded config from app-config.yaml
[0] <i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
[0] <i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:3000/, http://[::1]:3000/
[0] <i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/Users/robertsa1/src/scratch/dev10/bleh/backstage/packages/app/public' directory
[0] <i> [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to '/index.html'
[0] <i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /catalog?filters%5Bkind%5D=component&filters%5Buser%5D=all
[1] Backend failed to start up Error: Invalid configuration schema in ../../node_modules/@backstage/plugin-proxy-backend/config.d.ts, the following definitions are not supported:
[1]
[1]   Partial<{[key:string]:string;Authorization:string;authorization:string;'X-Api-Key':string;'x-api-key':string;}>
[1]     at /Users/robertsa1/src/scratch/dev10/bleh/backstage/node_modules/@backstage/config-loader/dist/index.cjs.js:348:15
[1]     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
[1]     at compileTsSchemas (/Users/robertsa1/src/scratch/dev10/bleh/backstage/node_modules/@backstage/config-loader/dist/index.cjs.js:322:27)
[1]     at async collectConfigSchemas (/Users/robertsa1/src/scratch/dev10/bleh/backstage/node_modules/@backstage/config-loader/dist/index.cjs.js:299:21)
[1]     at async Object.loadConfigSchema (/Users/robertsa1/src/scratch/dev10/bleh/backstage/node_modules/@backstage/config-loader/dist/index.cjs.js:481:15)
[1]     at async Object.createConfigSecretEnumerator (/Users/robertsa1/src/scratch/dev10/bleh/backstage/node_modules/@backstage/backend-app-api/dist/index.cjs.js:195:18)
[1]     at async loadBackendConfig (/Users/robertsa1/src/scratch/dev10/bleh/backstage/node_modules/@backstage/backend-common/dist/index.cjs.js:400:28)
[1]     at async main (webpack-internal:///./src/index.ts:83:20)
```

I cannot see how this is now an issue when this file has been present since I started my work.

even going and doing `npx @backstage/create-app@latest` in a new folder comes up with the same error....

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this issue today, a version upgrade of Backstage fixed it:

`yarn backstage-cli versions:bump`

https://github.com/backstage/backstage/issues/19463